Halachic source for R' Yitzchok Meir Morgenstern praying late
As we all know there are halachic times to pray. I recently discovered that R' Yitzchok is known (to some level) for praying late among other things.
I know he's a Mekubal and that's why he's one of my favourites however I find hard to believe he starts Shacharis after the halachic time has passed (I even read about him starting at 2:30PM).
Can anyone elucidate this matter a little bit? With all the due respect, he is one of the holiest of Israel. I just ask out of curiosity, not to disrespect him.
Thanks.

Is this question enhanced by including the name of the Mekubal in question? Writing about specific practices that contradict normative halacha may be lashon hora.

See Shu"t Eretz Tzvi Siman 36 for a psuedo-halachic rationalization of tzaddikim missing zman tefillah

@chortkov2 As I stated it's not to speak Lashon hara, just to clarify that this is a practice made by a gadol beIsrael, not just a random guy who misses zman tefillah. Also thanks for the answer.

Welcome to MiYodeya Netanel and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!
